# Query on Slicing a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

How do I print the reverse of a specific selection of a list ?

For example, I have a list,

`a = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88]`

I expect a[1:4:-1] to print [44,33,22], but it gives an empty list.

I have seen [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing/509295#509295), but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: [This answer on Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/364696) directly addresses how negative strides affect the interpretation of start and stop; it would answer your question by itself.

Comment: Note that 99% of the time, trying to mix selection and reversing in the same slice is just confusing as hell, and unless performance *really* counts, it's easier to just do the forward slice and follow with the canonical reversing slice, e.g. in this case `a[1:4][::-1]`. `a[1:4]` gets the elements you want, `[::-1]` produces the reversed version of the selected elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python slicing syntax, when 3 parameters are provided, is `[start:stop:step]`

In order to get the value `[44, 33, 22]`, you'd need to write the slice like this: `a[3:0:-1]`

This works because the slice starts at index `3`, which has a value of `44`, and the slice stops before index `0`, meaning the last included index is `1` (with a value of `22`), based on the `step` value of `-1`.